# What version of sun grid engine am I running?

Tags: sun

I'm poring over the SGE documentation and I can't find a simple version kind of command.  In particular, I want to read up on this system that is already installed via Rocks 5.2.2 and I want to be sure I'm reading the right docs.  Is there an SGE command that will tell me the version?

It seems like there should be some kind of 'qstat --version' command, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are running rocks you can simply use:

```
rpm -qi sge
```

Otherwise

```
qstat -help
```

shows the version at the top of its output.

Comment: Erk!  I swear I ran that!  I didn't check the (very verbose) output well enough.  Thanks.